# Is there a way to disable formatting of a USB Flashdrive?

Tags: windows-xp, usb-drive, group-policy, data-protection

Can any script or setting be written (autorun file?) to **disable formatting of a USB Flashdrive?**  *(Win XP, via Windows Explorer > Format)*

I'm aware of [write-protection](http://www.sizzledcore.com/2008/07/19/how-to-write-protect-your-usb-flash-drive/), but I don't want to completely prevent modifying files, instead something like what a [Group Policy setting](http://www.experts-exchange.com/Microsoft/Windows_Security/Q_22533362.html) could do?

**Edit:** Really what I'm asking for is a **registry setting** or else that I can modify on USB drive startup to tell Win XP not to format drive X:

Comment: I guess the question is, what is the end result of what you're trying to achieve? This smells and feels like an IT question; not a programming question.

Comment: C'mon, i'm looking for a way to solve it using programming! There is no other way to configure an unknown machine to disable format!

Comment: So really what I'm asking for is a registry setting or else that I can modify on drive startup to tell Win XP not to format drive X:

Comment: not feeling the programming on this one, but I'll refrain, since my moderator "vote" is binding

Comment: @Jeremy:  There's no way to infer what question you're really asking: Hence the 'smells like' question. :-)  Now by 'drive startup'; do you mean when the USB stick is first inserted? Or when the system first boots?

Comment: I don't think this is Programming Related

Comment: I'm really surprised this hasn't been closed yet.

Comment: Is there any way to prevent other machines from formatting my usb flashdrive when they use my usb flashdrive in *their* machines? Though they should be allowed to write to the flashdrive. Is there any way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Format the things as NTFS. That should give you sufficient security. You need admin rights to the volume to reformat the USB stick. Anyone with those rights can by definition disable any protection you could enable. If you allow Everyone to create and modify files in the root directory and below, users can still write files as demanded.

Answer (score 2):

Registry key 'MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Winlogon\AllocateDASD' restricts the formatting and ejecting of external drives (see this [helpful Microsoft spreadsheet full of registry keys that the Group Policy editor controls](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=25250)).

Set it to 'Administrators' or another group which you can trust not to go formatting where they shouldn't.